# How to add an object to a Cache and Access the data from cache in MVC4?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, caching, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi all i have an object which returns data like this

```
         var productdetial=  {
                               "productId": "1",
                               "productname": "Casualshirts",
                               "productSkus": [
                                                   {
                                                     "Skuimage": "URL",
                                                     "SKU": [
                                                               {
                                                                  "ProducSKU": "Shoe1001",
                                                                  "Options": [
                                                                                {
                                                                                  "productOptions": [
                            {
                                "OptionID": "1",
                                "optionname": "Color",
                                "value": "Black"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "2",
                                "optionname": "Size",
                                "value": "S"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "3",
                                "optionname": "Fit",
                                "value": "Regular"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ProducSKU": "Shoe1002",
                "Options": [
                    {
                        "productOptions": [
                            {
                                "OptionID": "1",
                                "optionname": "Color",
                                "value": "Red"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "2",
                                "optionname": "Size",
                                "value": "S"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "3",
                                "optionname": "Fit",
                                "value": "Regular"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "ProducSKU": "Shoe1003",
                "Options": [
                    {
                        "productOptions": [
                            {
                                "OptionID": "1",
                                "optionname": "Color",
                                "value": "Orange"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "2",
                                "optionname": "Size",
                                "value": "S"
                            },
                            {
                                "OptionID": "3",
                                "optionname": "Fit",
                                "value": "Regular"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

now what i want is i want to keep this data in cache, and i am binding this data to my view ,now what i want is when ever i make a request from my now on i should be able to access data from the above object whihc is in cache...cana ny one help me how can i do this how do i add this object to a cache and access data from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put this in the Application cache so that you can access it from anywhere.

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["productdetial"] = productdetial;
```

Then you can access it from anywhere like this

```
ProductDetails object = (ProductDetails) HttpContext.Current.Application["productdetial"]
```

if you want to store and retrieve this a string than also this is possible. Note that if you need caching specific to user session then use "Session" table instead of "Application"

There is another type of cache OutputCache that can be applied on controller action as shown below. For duration of 300 seconds this will provide the cached output to the client.

```
[OutputCache(Duration=300, VaryByParam="none")]
 public ActionResult GetProductDetails()
 {
      //Fetch the data once and it will be cached for 300 seconds       
            return View(data);
 }
```

Looks like you need one of the above 2. There are other types of caching also like donut caching and donut hole caching which are applicable if you want only some portion of the view to be cached. In donut hole caching you can include the above cached action into another view as a action.

Comment: ....what is the ProductDetail in this statement  ProductDetails object = (ProductDetails) HttpContext.Current.Application["productdetial"]

Comment: It is type of the object stored in the Application cache, I assumed a type "ProductDetails". You can even store a json string. Then instead of "ProductDetails" use string to store and retrive objects. The Application cache is a kind of key value hash table. The key can be a simple string. The value can be a object of any type.

Answer (score 4):

You can use httpcontext cache:

```
if(HttpContext.Cache.Get("productdetial") == null)
{
  HttpContext.Cache.Add("productdetial", productdetial, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration,
                                          new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0), CacheItemPriority.Normal, null);
}else
{
  cached = (ProductDetails) HttpContext.Cache.Get("productdetial");
}
```

Comment: Really good if you just need to cache certain service calls in a controller action, and need the rest to be uncached.