# Dirty update for web based mobile app

Tags: javascript, sql-server, json, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I have the folllowing tech stack:

> SQLServer/MVC4/WebAPI backend and a HTML5/JqueryMobile frontend. Data transferred via JSON.

I would like to know how I can reduce the data tranferred via JSON. i.e. I don't want get data I already have from the server?

Are there any libraries, or design patters to use or research to help me in this. What is the architecture commonly used to solve this.

Comment: Want to cache? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12908382/how-to-add-an-object-to-a-cache-and-access-the-data-from-cache-in-mvc4

Comment: Thanks for your responses, I am using localStorage to store the JSON data from the server.. but I want the updates to perform better.. e.g. if i'm updating the product in localstorage, I only want what has changed to come across, e.g. the quantity. I don't want to receive the name/description etc as that is already in local storage.

Answer (score 0):

To minimise transferred data. You can use local caching.

HTML5 local storage and sessionStorage.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

If you will be handling real time data I like using Signal R to enable push updates to active subscribers, avoids the need for polling.

http://www.asp.net/signalr/

Remember to enable your webserver to cache data where appropriate.

Finally good old fashioned analysis of your objects to make sure you are not sending unecessary data. JSON.NET will allow very good control of what items appear in your serialized output.

Comment: I would like some more info on how(tools/techniques/tutorials) to do the last paragraphs. thanks again :)